# How to insert multiple values to User_defined table types within a function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
------------------CREATING THE UDDT--------------------------------------
Create type audit.table_list AS TABLE
(
     table_name nvarchar(50),     
)
-----------------CREATING THE FUNCTION-----------------------------------    
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[test1] (@list audit.table_list readonly) 
    returns nvarchar(255) 
    
    as
    Begin
    DECLARE @name varchar(50)
    select  @name = table_name from @list
    return @name
    end 
-----------------------------------------------------------
----SELECTING THE RETURNED FUNCTION------------------------
    DECLARE @audit audit.table_list
    INSERT INTO @audit(table_name) VALUES('aa'),('bb')
    SELECT dbo.test1(@audit)
---Alternative I tried which was not able to return----
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[test] (@list audit.table_list readonly) 
returns @table_list table (table_name nvarchar(255)) 
as
Begin
DECLARE @Modifieduddt audit.table_list;
INSERT INTO @Modifieduddt(table_name) values('aaa');
return @modifiedUddt
end
```

This is inserting only one row/record and replacing the previous value. When I am trying to pass parameter within the function as a table instead of varchar(50) it is not letting me return the parameter which referring to the UDDT. I am trying to insert multiple values to the column in the UDDT. My goal is to pass table_name as column but when I do that I can't return @name within function

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do with this function. In the first version why are you only selecting one arbitrary value? In the second, why are you passing in a list but then not selecting it?

Answer (score 1):

You pass in a table, and the SELECT in your UDF returns a result set which you then try to assign to @name which is NVARCHAR(255), and your UDF returns a NVARCHAR(255) result.  In other words, you're trying to assign a result set to a NVARCHAR(255) variable which won't work.

If you want to return all of the results then your function should return a table instead of an NVARCHAR(255).

```
--Returns all values from @list
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[test1] (@list audit.table_list readonly) 
    returns TABLE

    as
    RETURN (SELECT table_name FROM @list)

--Use the UDF
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[test1];
```

If you want only a single result from the UDF then leave the return type as NVARCHAR(255) and modify the query to add a WHERE clause, or a TOP, or something that will result in a single value that can be stored in a NVARCHAR(255) variable.

```
--Returns a single NVARCHAR(255) value from @list
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[test1] (@list audit.table_list readonly) 
    returns nvarchar(255) 
    
    as
    Begin
    DECLARE @name varchar(50)
    select TOP 1 @name = table_name from @list
    return @name
    end

--Use the UDF
SELECT [dbo].[test1];
```

Note the difference in how the function is called between the two.  The first makes the UDF a table-valued function (TVF), the second makes the function a scalar-valued function (SVF).  With a TVF you use the function as you would a table (basically, there are other considerations) and with a TVF you use the function as a scalar value.

Comment: Just Tried the first one and getting the below error message. I think it is expecting column names after 'returns table' Msg 178, Level 15, State 1, Procedure test2, Line 8 [Batch Start Line 0]
A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 31, Procedure test2, Line 9 [Batch Start Line 0]
Incorrect syntax near 'BEGIN'.

Comment: Ugh, sorry... was on autopilot.  I fixed the syntax in the first example.  You don't need the column names in the RETURNS TABLE part.

Comment: It works now, thanks!. in addition to this, I am wondering how to insert values to this before running the  SELECT * FROM [dbo].[test1]. I am getting  "Parameters were not supplied for the function"(which makes sense). Is it possible to embed INSERT INTO code within function to run the function or before running? I tried to run the following insert into in the new window by running this but didn't really help.  DECLARE @list audit.table_list
INSERT INTO @list(table_name) VALUES('aa'),('bb'). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Scratch that, I found it :) DECLARE @list audit.table_list
INSERT INTO @list(table_name) VALUES('aa'),('bb')
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[test3](@list);

Comment: I am not sure if this should be another question but post it here anyways -could create a new post if needed. Is it possible to call/use these inserted values in a stored proc by doing inner join with dbo_test1, dynamic sql, inserting it within proc by declaring, or using open cursor?

Comment: If you want to call the function for each value in a query result set you want to use CROSS APPLY.  Something like  `SELECT Col1, Test1Val FROM MyTable t CROSS APPLY dbo.test1(t.Col1);`  Here, Col1 exists in MyTable and Test1Val is a column in the results of dbo.test().